# Selected tab bar icons look fuzzy if not on Retina display

Tags: ios, user-interface, png

I am working on an iPhone app that has a tab bar. I made the tab bar icons using a vector graphics editor and exported them to PNG. The icons look fine, except when selected.

[image: screenshot of fine-looking button]
[image: screenshot of fuzzy-looking button]

This doesn't happen on the retina display.

I use `self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Symbol"];` to set the image.
Here is the actual PNG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChxHk.png (though it happens with all the images).

What can I do about this? Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you having this problem on a device or just in the simulator?

Comment: @Mark Adams my device has a Retina display so I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to happen when the images don't have a margin. If you add a margin of 2px it will look fine:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 copies of the image. One for normal or older devices, and one for retina display.

Your images should be named accordingly.

```
image1.png // older devices
image1@2x.png // for retina display. @2x is case sensitive as well
```

When you choose your image, be sure to choose the normal image. The OS will select the @2x image if it is capable of displaying it.